# Where does jupyter notebook store the inline image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Use `%matplotlib inline` we can plot an image, but where does `jupyter notebook` store that image file?

I open the `ipynb` file use `VS Code` and find something like:

[image: ipynb source code]

So the chars like `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAXIAAAD8CAYAAABq6S8VAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAADl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAbWF0cGxvdGxpYiB2ZXJzaW9uIDIuMi4zLCBodHRwOi8vbWF0cGxvdGxpYi5vcmcvIxREBQAAIABJREFUeJzsvWuMpNd55/d/q6q7rt1dfZmZnhtnhuSQtEjtiCNT5FqULUu2YS/WMGAgxm4AJUaMOF/2w8b5EGOxH4LkywKbOMinIIoRYG3YiOPL2ivbkmPLpkRKtiyRS5kacoamNDfOpXv63lVdVV2XNx+av9P/9/TbM01JdEbYPkCjqqveOu+5POf/PM//ec55kzRNdVgOy2E5LIflB7cU/v9uwGE5LIflsByW760cAvlhOSyH5bD8gJdDID8sh` is the character description of binary of the image?

Where I can find the documents of it?

Comment: That's the image, encoded in base64. You can decode it to get the binary data.

Comment: @KlausD, thanks for your comment.